# Mantaflow fire not appearing in the image saved after rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mantaflow

I have rendered an image that has mana flow fire and it is appearing on viewport and the render. But the image that is being saved on my computer doesnt have the fire. I am attaching images to explain it better.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Realized that because I was using transparent background, the fire was being masked out. Checking the alpha channel made me realize that fire was being masked.
This tutorial helped me out:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNnFfXxB2Dg&ab_channel=BlenderMadeEasy

Comment: Well, the tutorial shows a workaround, but you should be aware that this will not preserve the original quality of the fire - like being additive on non-transparent backgrounds. Actually at the time this tutorial was made I think I remember there was something wrong with the _Image Editor_ and even there the fire was invisible, whereas nowadays you can view it there, it's only lost when you save it as PNG. The _Set Alpha_ node for example now has (other than in the video) two modes, _Apply Mask_ or _Replace Alpha_. If you choose the first option the saved PNG will not show the fire either.

Comment: Yes. You are hundred percent right. So, I guess there is no perfect solution for this?

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but maybe a solution suitable for your needs. I mean it always depends on where and why you want to use the fire with a transparent image. For many cases this workaround might be good enough. In other cases, for example to use it in Blender's compositor later on and preserve the additive quality of the light, it might be better to save it as OpenEXR instead of PNG. But maybe other software cannot handle EXR or will handle it at least differently.